# Binding Drop Down Lists with Unique Data Value fields from multiple Sql Tables?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I would like to choose multiple columns from multiple SqlDatabase Tables for binding the DropDownLists with unique data value fields.

Here is my C# code with SqlQuery to choose multiple columns from Table1:

```
// Create a dropdownlist inside the dynamically created panel and insert in the 1st row 1st cell of dynamic html table
var DDL = new WebForms.DropDownList();
DDL.ID = "MainDDL";
SqlDataSource da = new SqlDataSource();
da.ConnectionString = connection;
string item = "--Select--";
da.SelectCommand = "SELECT DATA_TYPE + '_' + convert(varchar(10), ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DATA_TYPE))as DATA_TYPE, COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE (TABLE_NAME = 'MyTable1' AND COLUMN_NAME IN ('Column1','Column2','Column3','Column4','Column5'))";
DDL.DataSource = da;
DDL.DataTextField = "COLUMN_NAME";
DDL.DataValueField = "DATA_TYPE";
DDL.DataBind();
```

**Solution Required:**
Multiple columns to be selected from Multiple Sql Tables:

> **How to select  column1 from Mytable2 also in the following Sql Query**
>
> SELECT DATA_TYPE + '_' + convert(varchar(10), ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DATA_TYPE))as DATA_TYPE, COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE (TABLE_NAME = 'MyTable1' AND COLUMN_NAME IN ('Column1','Column2','Column3','Column4','Column5'))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q:** "How to include Mytable2 and its column1 in the following Sql Query"

**A:**

```
SELECT 
    DATA_TYPE + '_' + convert(varchar(10), ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DATA_TYPE))as DATA_TYPE, 
    COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE 
    (TABLE_NAME = 'MyTable1' AND COLUMN_NAME IN ('Column1','Column2','Column3','Column4','Column5'))
    OR
    (TABLE_NAME = 'MyTable2' AND COLUMN_NAME IN ('Column1'))
```